# SQL Sum of rows grouped by id

Tags: sql, sql-server

This SQL:

```
select Name,
       (select COUNT(1) from tbl_projects where statusId = tbl_sections.StatusId) as N
from tbl_sections
left join tbl_section_names on tbl_section_names.Id = NameId
```

Generates the follows data:

```
Name    N
Completed   133
Cancelled   100
Unassigned  1
Sales   49
Development 10
Development 4
Development 1
```

I'm trying to modify it so it returns the data as follows:

```
Name    N
Completed   133
Cancelled   100
Unassigned  1
Sales   49
Development 15
```

(ie, sum up the rows where the name is the same)

Can anyone suggest some clues on how to make this work ? I'm guessing I need a SUM and a GROUP BY, but it never even runs the query as all I get are errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. It sums `N` grouped by `Name`.

```
SELECT Name, SUM(N) 
FROM (
    SELECT Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM tbl_projects 
        WHERE statusId = tbl_sections.StatusId
    ) AS N
    FROM tbl_sections
    LEFT JOIN tbl_section_names ON tbl_section_names.Id = NameId
) a
GROUP BY a.Name
```

Comment: I wasn't missing much then, just encapsulate inside another select as use the previous select in the from so I can use it elsewhere. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select Name, count(p.statusid) N
from tbl_sections
left join tbl_section_names on tbl_section_names.Id = NameId
left outer join tbl_projects p on tbl_sections.StatusId = p.statusId 
group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Name, Sum(N) from
    (select Name,
       (select COUNT(1) from tbl_projects where statusId = tbl_sections.StatusId) as N
    from tbl_sections
    left join tbl_section_names on tbl_section_names.Id = NameId)
group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is giving you count per status, which means Development has sections with three different status's, and the query would reflect this and make more sense if you added the status as a column:

```
select Name, tbl_sections.StatusId,
       (select COUNT(1) from tbl_projects where statusId = tbl_sections.StatusId) as N
from tbl_sections
left join tbl_section_names on tbl_section_names.Id = NameId
```

I don't know the structure of your database, but I if you want a count of the number of sections per name, might be like this.  This basically will look at the result of the join, and then summarize it by telling you the number of times each unique name occurs:

```
select Name, count(*)
from tbl_sections
left join tbl_section_names on tbl_section_names.Id = NameId
Group By Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and give this a go.

```
select Name,
   SUM(select COUNT(1) from tbl_projects where statusId = tbl_sections.StatusId) as N
from tbl_sections
left join tbl_section_names on tbl_section_names.Id = NameId
group by Name
```